# Spark python3+pycharm+windows environment

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

version for all：

```
spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tar.gz    
hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz    
scala-2.12.6
PyCharm 2017.1.3
Anaconda3
windows 8.1
```

settings:

1. install or unzip JAVA/SCALA/SPARK/HADOOP and add them to environment
   variable
2. add the winutils and hadoop lib to D:\hadoop-2.7.3\bin for windows
   X64(https://github.com/rucyang/hadoop.dll-and-winutils.exe-for-hadoop2.7.3-on-windows_X64)
3. copy D:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark to D:\Program Files
   (x86)\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
4. [set pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Svyp.png)

example code :

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from random import random
from operator import add

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
        Usage: pi [partitions]
    """
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("PythonPi")\
        .getOrCreate()

    partitions = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 2
    n = 100000 * partitions

    def f(_):
        x = random() * 2 - 1
        y = random() * 2 - 1
        return 1 if x ** 2 + y ** 2 <= 1 else 0

    count = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, n + 1), partitions).map(f).reduce(add)
    print("Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / n))

    spark.stop()
```

whole stack trace for the error:

> "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\envs\my_new_env_python35\python.exe"
>   "D:/pyProject/spark session/run-tests.py" Using Spark's default log4j
>   profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>
> Setting default log level to "WARN". To adjust logging level use
>   sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
>       mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)   File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in
>   _get_module_details
>       **import**(pkg_name)   File "", line 961, in _find_and_load   File "", line
>   950, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked   File "", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible   File
>   "D:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark__init__.py",
>   line 44, in    File "", line 961,
>   in _find_and_load   File "", line 950, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked   File "", line
>   616, in _load_backward_compatible   File
>   "D:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py",
>   line 36, in    File "", line 961,
>   in _find_and_load   File "", line 950, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 646, in _load_unlocked   File "", line
>   616, in _load_backward_compatible   File
>   "D:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\java_gateway.py",
>   line 25, in    File "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\platform.py", line 886, in 
>       "system node release version machine processor")   File "D:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py",
>   line 393, in namedtuple TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required
>   keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module' [Stage 0:>
>   (0 + 2) / 2]18/05/29 08:59:20 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in
>   stage 0.0 (TID 0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did
>   not connect back in time  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)    at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:133)
>     ... 12 more 18/05/29 08:59:20 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in
>   stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver):
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in
>   time  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)    at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:133)
>     ... 12 more
>
> 18/05/29 08:59:20 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1
>   times; aborting job Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:/pyProject/spark session转化/run-tests.py", line 27, in 
>       count = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, n + 1), partitions).map(f).reduce(add)   File
>   "D:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 835, in reduce   File
>   "D:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py",
>   line 809, in collect   File
>   "D:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**   File
>   "D:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py",
>   line 63, in deco   File
>   "D:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver):
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in
>   time  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)    at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:133)
>     ... 12 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:934)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in
>   time  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed
>   out   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)    at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:133)
>     ... 12 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

### update

1.Typed pyspark in CMD runs fine

2.python version is using 3.5.4

Comment: do you have java installed? what is the version?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan have installed..jdk1.8.0_144